# Why doesn't Android Studio accept this xml? Why does it demand I draw it all with the mouse?

Tags: android, layout, constraints

Here is my activity_main.xml.  Can someone point out the flaw in it?

The Design screen puts all eight buttons in the upper left corner on top of each other, ignoring the Constraint declarations.

Further maddening is the apparatus provided for actually doing the constraints with the mouse.  It offers me the choice of objects to link to, but the options are either End_toEnd or Start_toStart!  How can I make a row like that?

I thought I could use pure text, so I created a c# app to convert an Excel array into the XML file below, that is, the Buttons (not the header), and its so quick and easy.  It will be a heartbreaker if there's no way to do it except the mouse, dragging the arrows hither and thither.

Here's the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/InitCaps"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/ic"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/AllCaps"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/AllCaps"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/ac"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/InitCaps"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Quotes"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Quotes"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/q"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/AllCaps"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Hyphens"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Hyphens"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/h"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Quotes"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Dot"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Dot"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/dot"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Hyphens"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Comma"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Comma"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/comma"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Dot"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Undo"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Undo"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/undo"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Comma"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Redo"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Redo"
    android:layout_width="43dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/redo"
    android:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Undo"
    android:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah!  You know, I had "app:"  on the constraints to start with, but a couple of errors, I guess, caused Android Studio to order me to substitute "android:".

Now with the errors fixed, I thought, "try app again".

It worked.  Sorry to be a bother.